# How do I echo PHP code from database and make the syntax highlighted?

Tags: php

Is it good for users to be allowed to insert PHP code as an input and then store to database? If yes how can we echo out the inputs and display them in a page safely without losing syntax highlighting? 
I tried to echo it out this way but it tends to execute on the webpage

```html
 echo''.$row['input'].'';
```

Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your code samples in the database using `htmlentities` etc. So

```
<?php
//comment
?>
```

It must look like this in your MySQL table:

```
&lt;?php // comment ?&gt;
```

Create a PHP page that can SELECT the entries from the database table. It must include:

```
<head>
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
</head>
```

Echo your code sample from your query something like:

```
echo '<pre class="prettyprint">'.$row['code_sample'].'</pre>';
```

Comment: i have syntax highlighting enabled already with prettifier. my syntax highlighting stops working if i use  htmlentities.i dont know why

Comment: it looks thesame with the one am using but downloaded mine from google and included it on site head section. this is the link i downloaded from  http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/downloads/list. and this one is for the documentation   https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Comment: thank you very much for your efforts @foxbeefly.. it works that way but all the user inputs must not be codes so i want the user to declare the <pre> tag anytime he wish to insert code..this means the <pre> will be inserted into database and encoded with htmlspecialchars or so

Comment: So give more info: how is user adding text and code? How are you storing it? You could split the code out of the rest of the text by looking for the <pre> and </per> tags, and treat the code as code and the rest as text.

Comment: thanks alot i have finally done it..your suggestion brought an open door, i stored everything in database with htmlspecialchars then when i want to echo it out i searched for <pre class="prettyprint"> and </pre> (i.e the encoded one of it) and used php str_replace to change it to the normal html tag..its working now thanks